# How to join value from related table to Laravel eloquent collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have one table ITEMS (sku, title) and other HISTORY (sku,points,startdate).
Table HISTORY serves as history for item points changes.

I would like to join latest points when calling

```
$items = \App\Items::all();
```

Which is best way to do it?

I know i can make custom attribute, but it seems that then i have too many queries (since for each item it will make aditional query?)

Also i can make relation:

```
public function points()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\History','sku','sku')->orderBy('startdate','DESC');
    }
```

But is there better way?
br
Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the latest record, the best option is the `hasOne` relationship you've shown. That way, the relationship can be eager loaded, so you're only calling 2 queries, instead of N+1 queries.

Relationship:

```
public function currentPoints()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\History','sku','sku')->orderBy('startdate','DESC');
}
```

Usage:

```
$items = \App\Items::with('currentPoints')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
 class Items extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'sku';

    public function points()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\History','sku','sku')->orderBy('startdate','DESC');
    }


    public function getItems(){
         $items = \App\Items::with('points')->get();
    }
}
```